# Globale Variable use and increment that variable values in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

hi I search every where I couldn't found any answer or solution for this, I need the way of doing this ; my requirement is I have XML like this

```
 <mail>
     <hotel>
           <name>asd</name>
           <cost>50</cost>
     </hotel>
      <hotel>
           <name>sdesd</name>
           <cost>60</cost>
     </hotel>
    <totalcost>170</totalcost>
 </mail>
```

I have XSLT file like this

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <html>
      <xsl:for-each select="mail/hotel">
        <tr>HOTEL NAME : <xsl:valueof select="name"></tr>
        <tr>COST <xsl:valueof select="cost"></tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
        <tr>TOTAL COST WITH TAX <xsl:valueof select="mail/totalcost"></tr>
        <tr>TAX <b><xsl:valueof select="_____"></b></tr> (for this place I want to calculate cost values comeing under hotel child and set)   
   </html>
</xsl:template>
```

like in java we initialize globe variable and set increment wise values inside the for loop, and use that final out come out side of the loop how can I do that in this XSLT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to compute a sum then use e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="sum(mail/hotel/cost)"/>`.

Answer (score 0):

Variables are "values" in xslt, you can set it only once.

For common operations look for language operations, such as sum() that should do just fine for your example.

If you need something more complex you can use a recursive call of template with variable(s).

E.g.

```
<xsl:template match="/" name="operation">
    <xsl:param name="value">0</xsl:param>
    <xsl:if test="$count < 100">
        <xsl:call-template name="operation">
            <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$value + 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$count >= 100">
        <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: this is how to increment ryhgt? I need some globle varible to be assigned with values like in java " 

class ASD{ 
  public a = 0.0;
  for(loop){
    a = somevalue + a;
  }
  sysout(a+"");
}

Comment: You should do fine if you replace ifs in example with your conditions and +1 with your operation.

Comment: Some other solution found buddy.. thnx a lot for the help :)